# Convert maven web module to google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-3

I'm new to the google cloud. I have a maven web project (actually its a maven module under a parent project) and i want to deploy it to the google cloud. the web application is quite independent, dependencies wise. it can be deployed on any web server or application server. i use mysql as my DB. it uses spring mvc and uses hibernate as JPA provider (using spring orm) and all these dependencies are provided and compiled in the war file. so...
1) is it possible to just deploy the war file to the google cloud without converting the project to a google app engine project?
2) if not, is there any way to convert my existing project to a google app engine project and still use maven?
3) maybe a noob question but, can i use mysql on the google cloud?

i may have more questions as i go along but for now i guess this will do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, at least you need to [add some config files.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) It also depends on the APIs/libs your web app uses. GAE [does supports a subset of Java APIs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist). Most notably classic database access is not supported.
2. Yes, deploying via maven is supported via [`maven-gae-plugin`](http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/). Still, the biggest obstacle would be the existing code using unsupported Java APIs.
3. [CloudSQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) is based on MySQL, so SQL syntax and JDBC API are almost the same.